# bs4.element.Tag and split, python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use the split method, but I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong, tell me please?

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
def get_parsed_page(url, delay=0.5):
    data = solver.request_get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(data.solution.response, "lxml")

def get_matches():
    global MATCH_WITH_COUNTDOWN
    matches = get_parsed_page("https://****/matches/")
    matches_list = []

    matchdays = matches.find_all("div", {"class": "upcomingMatchesSection"});
    for match in matchdays:
        matchDetails = match.find_all("div", {"class": "upcomingMatch"})
        print(type(match.find({'div': {'class': 'matchDayHeadline'}})))
        date = match.find({'div': {'class': 'matchDayHeadline'}}).split()[-1]
```

Expected no error. Im trying remove split

Comment: Try: match.find({'div': {'class': 'matchDayHeadline'}}).text.split()[-1]

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to *`match.find({'div': {'class': 'matchDayHeadline'}})`* not finding anything; you cannot apply `.split()` to a result that does not exist, so the error is raised.

Also, `.split` is generally applied to strings, not Tags. Try

```py
        date = match.find({'div': {'class': 'matchDayHeadline'}})
        if date: date = date.text.split()[-1]
```

Note that this will only avoid the error, so you might just get <kbd>`date`=**`None`**</kbd> instead. If it's happening consistently, you should inspect *`data.solution.response`* more carefully to see if you're using the correct class or if the date field even exists in the fetched html.